# Populate Drop Down List & Text Boxes in ASP.Net using C# and JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

This is my first question on Stack overflow so thank you in advance for any help/ advice given.

I am currently making a "Library Database" using only ASP.Net and C#. It is a university assignment and we are limited to this, Data must be saved and withdrawn using JSON.

While i have been able to Add a book listing and display the listing in a grid view, I need to be able to display and edit the information using a standard form, using a drop down list and text boxes to display each section.
The below code snippet shows the Book class used to keep all the variables for the JSON File

```
 public class Book
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
    public string publisher { get; set; }
    public string isbn { get; set; }

    public Book(string id, string title, string author, string year, string publisher, string isbn)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.year = year;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.isbn = isbn;       
    }
}
```

The below code shows the Other class being used to generate a list from the above variables.

```
public class BookList
{
    public List<Book> bookList { get; set; }

    public BookList()
    {
        bookList = new List<Book>();
    }
}
```

The below code shows what i currently have for my Edit Book Page.

```
public partial class EditBook : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public const string FILENAME = @"C:\Users\User\Documents\Assessments\19383038_CSE2ICX_Assignment3\JsonFiles\BookList.Json";
    string jsonText = " ";
    BookList bookList = new BookList();  

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            jsonText = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {

        }
        BookList bookList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BookList>(jsonText);
        JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            ddl.DataTextField = "id";
            ddl.DataValueField = "id";
            ddl.DataSource = bookList.bookList;
            ddl.DataBind();
        }

    }

    protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtEnterID.Text = "";
    }
```

Now, I have managed to populate the Drop Down List, but hours of research and racking my brain, i cannot find a way to translate that onto the text boxes. Currently I have no way of having the Textboxes
a) Identify which value the Drop down list is using
b) Using that value to determine which variable of the JSON file it uses, and from which group.

Now im aware that its very likely I cannot use this method to populate the text boxes, and probably need to start from scratch. I don't need the code handed to me, but i would appreciate if someone could give me an example snippet, or push me on to the write track with how to tackle this task.

Please no Ajax, Jquery or java.

Thank you again if you made it to the end.

Comment: I don't really understand. Do you need to populate the TextBox values based on the DropDownList value in the SelectedIndexChanged method? And that the values are in `bookList`?

Comment: Btw you are reading and converting your file for no reason every time you load the page.

Comment: Sorry guess that was a little confusing. to give an example in a better format. If i have a list of 10 books. each with the Id 1-10. each ID contains a book witha  different name, author, year etc. When i select a book ID from the drop down list i need to have each of the text fields populate with the relevant information
e.g. ID 1
Title = Harry potter
Author = JK Rowling
year = 1997
etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this inside the SelectedIndexChanged method:

```
//get your list of books
BookList bookList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BookList>(jsonText);

//select the correct book from the list using Linq and the selected value from ddl
var book = bookList.bookList.Where(x => x.id == ddl.SelectedValue).FirstOrDefault();

//show the book properties in the textboxes
txtEnterID.Text = book.id;
txtTitle.Text = book.title;
```

Comment: Just tried it out and its telling me there's no object reference. So i must be doing something wrong/putting it in the wrong spot.

Comment: That probably means that there is no book with the is that comes from the ddl. If that is the case then the object `var book` is null and will throw that exception if you try to access it's properties. Can you debug what the value is of the ddl and if a book exists in the list with that id.

Comment: And you declare the list twice (`BookList bookList =`). One inside the page_load and one above it.

Comment: Okay so, I was placing the code in the wrong order. What you have given me perfectly identifies the 1st set of values in my JSON file, giving the id and titles to the relevant text boxes. Thank you very much for that Its further than I have gotten all night. 
The issue still remains that when I click to change the Id though the fields do not change with it. Is this code snippet intended to perform that function as well?
If so, While i may have a few reasons why that may be, i'm not experienced enough to explain it clearly.

Comment: Did you add `AutoPostBack=true` to the DropDownList on the aspx page?

Comment: Yes, But i need to leave the ddl references in the !ispostback or it constantly resets the the first ID when i change it. This seems to cause me alot of errors when i move other code outside, and i cant put anything in the selected index changed void.

Comment: That only happens when you bind outside an `IsPostBack` check, which you are not doing, or the EnableViewState is set to false or you reset the DLL to it's original value somewhere else.

Comment: Disregard that last one, I had some code i didnt properly get rid of, its 2am where I live so my heads a bit all over the place. It seems to be working now. Thank you very much for all your help and patience with me :) I should be able to move onto figuring out how to edit and delete the existing entries.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had time to test this code. But the ideia is pretty simple. You get the `sender` variable and convert it to `DropDownList` class and use its `SelectedItem` property.

```
  protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedValue = (Book)((DropDownList)sender).SelectedItem.Value;
        txtEnterID.Text = selectedValue.title;
    }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I think I get what were doing here, but where is the Combo Box Namespace coming from?

Comment: It was just an example, which class does ddl variable belongs to?

Comment: Ah i see what youre getting at now.
ddl is the ID for my Drop Down List, not a variable.

Comment: You need to convert sender to ddl's class and get the property that represent the current selected item (it is probably a Book object).

Comment: This is not gonna work. A DropDownList only contains items of type  `ListItem`. You cannot cast them back to a `book`.

Comment: I see. What about 'ddl.SelectedItem.Value'?

Comment: A ListItem only has two string properties, Text and Value. So `ddl.SelectedItem.Value` gives you the same result as `ddl.SelectedValue`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works, but this usually works for me, so I hope it helps you too.

```
 protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtEnterID.Text = ddl.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();

    }
```

Also, could I ask why you load the dropdownlist data text field as id and not book name?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment, I've already sorted the issue.
I load it as ID as its an assignment requirement (Silly i know). I would rather go by book name but in practicality it doesn't change anything.